# Azure Based DDOS Mitigation, Azure Based Firewall?

Tags: ddos

I'd like to mitigate DDOS attacks, for an Azure vm server (just TCP ports 80 and 443).  Azure appears to be a great solution.  I can't find any Azure documentation, as to if there is an Azure firewall, which I can configure, in front of my Azure vm server. For example, if there is a 10 Gigabit/second UDP attack, I don't want those packets to hit my Azure vm server.  Is there some Azure firewall, which will prevent those UDP packets from hitting my Azure vm server?

Comment: There isnt a real question here...

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft provided me with a web page, with the answer.  In summary, the Azure cloud has a cloud firewall which will take the DDOS hit, so that no DDOS traffic hits my vm guest.  Here is the [web page URL](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-set-up-endpoints/).

Comment: Not a true answer. In no way does it say the firewall will scrub or handle DDoS traffic, nor should you expect it, since that isn't what firewalls do or are designed to do. In fact, this article plainly states that DDoS mitigation will NOT happen, simply by saying how to open a port to allow all traffic from the internet to your VM (what you DON'T want when you are under a DDoS attack). You deny access to that port, you deny it to everyone. DDoS mitigation works by scrubbing the DDoS traffic while allowing legitimate traffic through. The kind that is worth it anyways.

Comment: I disagree with DubStep.  The question stated that only TCP 80/443 needed to be protected, and protected from only a UDP attack.  A firewall can simply drop all of the UDP attack by looking at the protocol field.  There is no need for scrubbing or other advanced techniques to filter the UDP attack.  I'm sure DubStep agrees, but DubStep most likely didn't carefully read the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a thought that Microsoft can help for DDoS mitigation in your environment. Well, Microsoft has its own DDoS defense system, but it is designed for only network-layer **high** volume attack to protect Azure customer tenants. It basically means there is no guarantee from Microsoft to prevent from an attack of smaller volume which you may be the target. Microsoft also has no official information regarding how high the network volume attack is. Azure also doesn't provide mitigation or actively block network traffic to customer deployment at application-layer attack.

To mitigate a direct attack to your virtual machine, you shouldn't have its public IP address over the Internet. Instead, you should build a bastion host in front of your main virtual machine. The connection between the bastion host and your virtual machine should be P2S (point-to-site) VPN. It means there is not any Internet-bound traffic going directly to your virtual machine. If this virtual machine is hosted a web application, then you can just use Azure Application Gateway or open-source firewall.

Next, enable Azure DDos protection which is documented here (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/ddos-protection-overview). You have nothing to do than just enabling this service.

More advanced, if budget is not a concern, look into 3rd virtual appliance for example [Barracuda](https://www.barracuda.com/programs/azure), [F5](https://f5.com/about-us/blog/articles/f5-now-available-in-microsoft-azure) or so on to help protect volumetric attack.

Comment: I disagree with Thuan Ng.  The question stated that only TCP 80/443 needed to be protected, and protected from only a UDP attack.  The Azure firewall can simply drop all of the UDP attack by looking at the protocol field.  There is no need for scrubbing or other advanced techniques to filter the UDP attack.  I'm sure Thuan Ng agrees, but Thuan Ng most likely didn't carefully read the original question.